# Construct a free abelian group F with basis X of any given set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some problem with the free abelian group with respect to its basis.
Here are something from the book *Algebra* by Thomas W. Hungerford:

> Given any set $X$, the proof of Theorem 1.1 indicates how to construct a free abelian group $F$ with basis $X$.

Let's forget the theorem 1.1, but how could we know that any finite distinct elements of $X$ is linearly independent since the author regard $X$ as a basis of $F$ instead of just a set？

**EDIT**: You may thought I am not read the book carefully since the author had answered me on the book. Yes, it is.  But I didn't got the idea so I post this here.

Comment: Given a set $X$, you construct $F(X)$, the free abelian group with basis $X$ as formal finite sums $\sum_i n_i x_i$, with integer coefficients. Then $X$ is a basis. The actual construction of $F(X)$ is as follows: Take $F(X) := \{f : X \to \mathbb Z : f(x) \neq 0 \text{ for only finitely many } x \}$. The operations are point wise. On the other hand: Given a free abelian group, it has a basis. This means that the group is finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$ module.

Comment: @AndréSchemaitat But if both number 2 and 4 in the set X? Does X independent?

Comment: @Brooks: Yes, it still is, we think of all elements of $X$ to be uncorrelated things. E.g, you can construct a free abelian group from the set $X = \{ \text{cat}; \text{dog}; \text{Garfield} \}$, here we just regard cat, dog, and Garfield to be 3 independent 'vectors', and 'multiply some scalar (any elements in $\mathbb{Z}$)' before them, and 'sum' them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the context of the book you mention, but I can answer *in general*: for *any* set $X$, the free abelian group with basis $X$ is the $\mathbf Z$-module $\mathbf Z^{(X)}$ of mappings from $X$ to $\mathbf Z$ *with finite support*, i.e. the set of $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(x)=0$, except for a finite number of $x$s.

Among these functions, you have the functions $\varphi_x$ such that, for all $x'\in X$,
$$\varphi_x(x')=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } x'=x\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$
i.e. the characteristic function of the sets $\{x\},\enspace x\in X$. It is easy to check these functions are linearly independent over $\mathbf Z$.

Thus the free abelian group in question is the abelian group with basis $\{\varphi_x\mid x\in X\}$, since for any function $f$ with finite support:
$$f(x_1)=\lambda_1,\dots,f(x_n)=\lambda_n, f(x)=0\enspace\text{for any other }x,$$
we can write
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\varphi_{x_i}(x).$$

Last step: the canonical map $\begin{aligned}[t]X &\rightarrow \mathbf Z^{(X)} \\x&\mapsto \varphi_x\end{aligned}$ is injective, so we can identify $X$ to a subset of $ \mathbf Z^{(X)} $. One often denotes $\varphi_x$ as $[x]$, so that an element of the free abelian group with basis $X$ may be described as a formal finite linear combination:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i[x_i]$$
of elements of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

For a set $X$, the free abelian group $F(X)$ with basis $X$ is by (a) definition the group with presentation $\langle{x\in y\,:\, xy = yx\text{ for all $x, y\in X$}}\rangle$. The set $X$ doesn't have any other structure a priori. To use more pedantic notation, $F(X)$ is simply $\mathbb{Z}^{\# X} = \bigoplus_{x\in X} \mathbb{Z}e_x$, where $e_x$ is an arbitrary basis element corresponding to $x\in X$. The set $X$ is clearly a basis of $F(X)$, but it's not assumed that $X$ has any sort of linear independence, or even a defined group operation, on it beforehand.

More formally, the free abelian group $F(X)$ on a set $X$ is defined to be the image of $X$ under the adjoint of the forgetful functor from abelian groups to sets: $\operatorname{Map}(X, A^{\text{set}}) = \operatorname{Hom}(F(X), A)$, where $A^{\text{set}}$ is the underlying set of an abelian group $A$ and $\operatorname{Map}(X, Y)$ denotes the space of arbitrary functions of sets $f:X \to Y$. Unravelling that definition (which is a bit disingenuous, since the existence and uniqueness of such an adjoint isn't automatic), $F(X)$ is the unique abelian group such that for any function of sets $f:X \to A$ with an abelian group, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\bar f:F(X) \to A$ with $\bar f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in X$. (I'm being a bit sloppy with notation here, but this is a concrete enough construction that it's not a big deal.)

Comment: You write that the free abelian group on X is defined to be the adjoint if some functor, and you meant to write that it is the value of that adjoint on X.

Comment: Answers to questions which are about a confusion in basic algebra involving adjoint functors never cease to amaze me, by the way!

Comment: If I remember correctly, that is actually the approach that's taken in Hungerford, which the OP is using. (It's written out explicitly in terms of a commutative diagram, as I did in the latter half of the second paragraph. I might also be thinking of the construction Hungerford uses for free groups.) You can ignore the more abstract approach and just explicitly construct a free group or free abelian group, but that's a bit unmotivated and begs the question of why that particular presentation is unique; the adjoint property is, after all, the point of freeness.

Comment: The thing is, it is the free group construction and friends which are the origin and motivation for adjoints, not the other way around!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with that. The free group construction via a commutative diagram is exactly the same as the adjoint one, just with different language. On the other hand, adjoints pop up in, for example, questions of representability in algebraic topology.

Comment: You'll agree that if someone is confused about whether the elements of $X$ are linearly independent in the free group generated by $X$, anything related to representability in algebraic topology is somewhat irrelevant, no? I am not saying that the free group construction and adjoints are not related: I am saying that using the second to explain the first is rather anomalous.

Comment: My point is that the adjoint construction is a simple and broadly useful thing, while setting up an ad hoc definition is less so. (For example, if you define a free group as one admitting a particular presentation, then you have to deal with the fact that presentations aren't unique, or even easy to find.) If you don't like this answer, feel free to downvote it or add a better one.